# What is a Aged Rope Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, word-property, anagram

If a phrase adheres to a certain rule, I call it a Aged Rope Phrase™.

[image]

Text-only version in CSV form:

```
"Enamel Tar","A Chaplain Labouring"
"Enable Lane","A Paleface Meets Minor"
"Beer Nice","Therefore Flows Typo"
"He Houses Four","Five Fog Lot"
"Adequate Ford Mesh","Fifteen Smog Tint"
"A Lethal Letter","Preacher Tests Why"
"A Nutmeat Atoll","A Buttercup Chlorine"
"Arterial Bum Pure","Offer Loft Wigs"
"Hare Vent","A Affectionately Griever Mops"
"Deplaned Thump Unit","Fishermen John Tool Top"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that an Aged Rope Phrase is

> An anagram of a work by Edgar Allan Poe ("Aged Rope" is an anagram of "Edgar Poe")

Examples

> Enamel Tar = Tamerlane
>  Enable Lane = Annabel Lee
>  Nice Beer = Berenice
>  He Houses Four = House of Usher
>  Adequate Ford Mesh = (The) Masque of (the) Red Death
>  A Lethal Letter = Tell-Tale Heart
>  A Nutmeat Atoll = Mellonta Tauta
>  Arterial Bum Pure = (The) Premature Burial
>  Hare Vent = The Raven
>  Deplaned Thump Unit = (The) Pit and the Pendulum

It seems as though the Not Aged Rope Phrases are

> Anagrams of Works by [Rufus Wilmot Griswold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rufus_Wilmot_Griswold), a contemporary rival of Poe

Examples

> A Chaplain Labouring = Biographical Annual
>  A Paleface Meets Minor = American Female Poets
>  Therefore Flows Typo = Poetry of the Flowers
>  Five Fog Lot = Gift of Love
>  Fifteen Smog Tint = Gift of Sentiment
>  Preacher Test Why = The Cypress Wreath
>  A Buttercup Chlorine = The Republican Court
>  Offer Loft Wigs = Gift of Flowers
>  A Affectionately Griever Mops = Gift Leaves of American Poetry
>  Fishermen John Tool Top = The Prose of John Milton

Comment: So I'm an unwashed mass fresh from the HNQ. I do not know the ways of this strange microcommunity. How the hell are you supposed to figure this stuff out?

Comment: It's a matter of trying different things, and knowing what to try. It comes with experience and hanging around here a little while.